# Magento 2x Flat Rate show wrong price?

Tags: shipping-methods, magento2.2.3

Flat Rate  ==>Type ==> Per Order Option not working price change when add more than one product magento 2.2.3 both Main Website & Default Config store view .

[image: both main & default store view enter image description here]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked on store view configuration ?

Comment: yes , both main & default store view